# Credit Card Billing Cycle

Tags: credit, billing

I am considering getting the QuikTrip credit card offered by First Bankcard. After the credit card application is approved, when does the billing cycle begin? I have contacted First Bankcard's Customer Service but they could not answer the question.

Comment: Does it matter when the billing cycle begins?

Comment: Business cards typically begin and end on the first and last of the month.  Consumer cards are variable and usually dependent upon when an account is opened.  Provided you did not make any charges, you can probably have that day changed if it is not to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask the bank. There is no standard, and different card issuers behave in significantly different ways. Even within a specific bank, there may not be consistency from product to product, or even within a product, depending on when you opened it or other happenings:

- Some banks have all their cards cycle on the same day of the month (i.e. the 1st or the 15th).
- Some banks have all their cards cycle on the anniversary of it's open date (i.e. if you open it on the 8th it cycles on the 8th of every month) with rounding up or down for cards issued on the 29th - 31st.
- Some banks have a set number of cycle batches, and your card is randomly assigned to one of those batches. for instance, they may have a batch that cycles on the 5th, the 15th, and the 25th of every month. New cards are randomly assigned in a way that keeps the sizes of the three batches consistent.
- Some banks let you change your cycle date. Others don't.
- Some banks used to use one of these methods (say, every card cycles on the 1st) but then switched to another (maybe they allow new cards to cycle on their anniversary date, but anyone with a card before the change still cycles on the 1st).
- Sometimes, when a bank merges with another, the customers keep the cycle dates they had with their old bank. In other mergers, everyone from one bank is "forced" to convert to the cycle dates the other bank used.